# Using ASIO with VST Host and Windows Sounds at the same time

Tags: software, midi-controller-keyboard, computer

First of all, I know there's related posts: [How to make ASIO work with multiple programs simultaneously : how can I listen to Guitar Rig plus something else through the same interface?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20484/how-to-make-asio-work-with-multiple-programs-how-can-i-listen-to-guitar-rig-plu/20489#20489)
But they don't answer my question that is:

> Is there any way to use **ASIO** with some **VST Host and Windows
>   Applications** (Web Browser, Media player, etc.) at the same time **with just one real sound card**?

1. I know it is possible via software using [O Deus ASIO Link](http://odeus-audio.com.au/Odeus/AsioLink).
   Unfortunately, their free version mutes all sounds for 5 seconds each
   1 minute. They work emulating a Sound Card Driver and routing
   it to VST Application and Windows use that Sound Card Driver as Default.
2. I also know that it is posssible via [JACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit), but after trying
   a lot to get it working on Windows, I could not hear it clear
   (sounds was cracking). I could not find a 100% working tutorial for
   *Windows 8*. **:(**

### Edit 1:

I installed Cubase, it comes with "ASIO DirectX **Full Duplex** Driver".

I think the trick is this driver that is installed. But if **I change the Cubase' driver to ASIO4ALL** (which has lower latency for live playing) **I have that same problem**.

Comment: ASIO shouldn't monopolise the card; other apps ought to still be able to play through it - unless that's some kind of Windows limitation. I do similar all the time, running Cubase doesn't stop, for instance, iTunes playing over the same output, even simultaneously

Comment: What are the version of your Windows? I've heard that at Windows XP it works fine.

Comment: I'm on Mac. It's possibly that coreAudio can do it & Windows can't - it's unfortunately always been quite poor at audio routing.

Comment: I've had this multiclient ASIO problem with Lexicon Alpha. The best solution I found after tons of research is using Asio Link Pro, and still there was a small latency that was annoying.
I have decided to buy a Steinberg UR22 MKII. I can confirm it works flawlessly, with no latency whatsoever, and without any special configuration. Their ASIO driver just works perfectly. I am playing Spotify / YouTube while playing my MIDI inside Ableton.

My setup is Windows 10 + Ableton Live 9.5.

Answer (score 2):

Cubase (at least 5+) can do this. You can set Cubase's sound card driver settings to have the sound card not be exclusively "owned" by Cubase so other applications can also use it while Cubase is running.

Comment: I don't have experience with ASIO4ALL and just little with the Cubase ASIO DirectX Full Duplex Driver since I always use the driver that ships with the audio interface (which is in almost any time the best to use if using a dedicated audio interface via USB, FW etc.). So yes, ASIO4ALL may act different as you described.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now with Voicemeeter Banana, which is fully functioning donationware. I set mine up this way to play piano:

Install Voicemeeter or V. Banana (After setup, needs to be running to get sound)

Control Panel/Sound/Hardware/Playback/Voicemeeter Aux Input/Set default/Ok (no AUX also works but want different one on Truepianos)

TruePianos/ Preferences/ASIO: Voicemeeter Virtual ASIO (both this and AUX work, but seems to have less latency if different from Control Panel)

Hardware Out A1 set to ASIO4ALL v2 (no other seems necessary)

Virtual Inputs A1 (one is VAIO, from Truepianos, other is AUX from Windows control panel)