# Is there a guitar amp simulator for windows that doesn't block other apps sounds?

Tags: software

I have Guitar Rig 5 that am using it with the Rocksmith cable, had to install something called "ASIO" to make it work because the other one (WASAPI) doesn't work with Rocksmith usb cable.

Guitar Rig, Asio and rocksmith cable work just fine until i decide to watch a youtube tutorial or open a tab in guitar pro, and i realized that the whole computer sound is turned off.

Been searching to solve this problem for the past ~5 days, installed ASIO4ALL, AsioLink and AsioServer but i really could not make it work as there is no clear instructions to do it.

Is there a solution for this please ? a guitar rig alternative maybe that works fine with rocksmith cable ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this question can help: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20484/how-to-make-asio-work-with-multiple-programs-simultaneously-how-can-i-listen-t/

Answer (score 1):

The Rocksmith audio cable forces Audio Exclusivity on the PC, this can be turned off in the PC's Audio Settings.

You'd be better off buying a dedicated USB audio interface, they can be found relatively cheaply, and will not force any kind of exclusivity as it will act as the sound card for the PC. Be aware though that some PCs introduce latency into signals with heavy processing, and might make practicing to Youtube difficult. I've had this issue in the past.

Comment: *ASIO* forces exclusivity (this is not a Rocksmith problem), and non-ASIO drivers are a primary reason for latency. However, the exclusivity is for one software package, not the whole audio subsystem so if the OP were to get a secondary device as described, then one could be used for computer audio, the other used for Guitar Simulation (using ASIO). This requires two sets of speakers or a mixer however.

Comment: I use the Rocksmith game, and it indeed does force Audio Exclusivity. I had to disable it to enable streaming of the game. If the OP got an interface, plugged the guitar into it, discarded the use of the Rocksmith cable and fired up Guitar Rig alongside a YouTube video, they'd be able to play along. Latency issues notwithstanding.

Comment: The Rocksmith game software has an exclusive mode setting. the Rocksmith cable does not. Note that the rocksmith cable is simply a USB microphone device where the mic head is replaced with a guitar pickup.