# Amp Simulation and YouTube with USB Headset

Tags: electric-guitar, software

When practising I can't be too noisy, so I have to use my headphones. But I hate wires, especially wires going to my headset. Therefore I use the wireless Logitech G933 gaming headset. It has a really low latency for gaming. The sound from games have an unnoticeable latency, so I assumed that I could just get an audio interface, plug my guitar in, and use amp simulation without much latency. I had bought a Behringer UMC22 audio interface, but I just can't manage to get a low latency.

Well, I can get a low latency, but this requires me to use the ASIO4ALL driver which takes exclusive control of my headset and I can't play along to songs or watch tutorials on YouTube.

The closest working solution (which wasn't playable due to the latency) was by using the ASIO4ALL drivers and VoiceMeeter.

With the current state of technology I can't believe that this is not possible. But I've searched and experimented for hours, and I can't find a working solution.. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Behringer don't make their own drivers, so you're stuck with what Windows can do with audio… which is not much. Maybe try [flexASIO](https://github.com/dechamps/FlexASIO) instead. I'm not on Win & don't use Behringer, so can't help much more.

Comment: See this question https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20484/how-to-make-asio-work-with-multiple-programs-simultaneously-how-can-i-listen-t

Comment: I use Mac, but Voicemeeter Banana might be something to try https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried flexASIO, but I couldn't get it to work. I'll try again though, maybe I can get it to work this time.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Sadly I wasn't able to find my answer there. I was hoping asking a similar question specific to my situation would give new solutions. I've also tried and tested a lot with Voicemeeter Banana, but I couldn't get the latency down to a playable amount..
Thank you both for the suggestions though!

Comment: This won't help you, but on the Mac things work by default with regular audio APIs that every application uses, no need for 3rd party ASIO things which exist on Windows to hack around Microsoft's stuff. Anyway, one way to get this to work is to use an ASIO audio interface with more inputs than just the guitar. If you have, say, 4 input channels, you can physically connect the PC's normal audio line output to the audio interface's extra inputs, say, channels 3-4, and your guitar to channel 1. Mix all the channels in your DAW and you'll have low-latency guitar, and backing tracks from Youtube.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Hmm.. A virtual machine would probably add quite a bit of latency as well, but maybe I could set up a hackintosh from the parts I have laying around from my previous pc. Thanks for the suggestion.
Taking the output from my PC doesn't work either. I have a 5.1 speaker setup which takes up the required outputs..
When playing guitar I don't mind it if there is a bit of delay on the PC's sound, so I might be able to find a way to virtually route my PC's sound to my DAW. It's worth giving a shot :)